# How Can I Pass jdbc.properties to Spring/Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am getting the following error while trying to pass in values from a properties file to Spring, so that I don't have to supply them directly in ***hibernate.cfg.xml***. Is there a better (and correct) approach? I know that the properties file is being referenced because if I put in in invalid password, it fails on that. I'd be grateful for any help.

```
WARNING: No connection properties specified - the user must supply JDBC connections
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:426)
```

This is applicationContext.xml:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="cmsutil"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:configurationClass="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"
          p:packagesToScan="cmsutil.*">

        <property name="exposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="false" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="txnManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <mapping resource="cmsutil.entity/contentcomponent.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Per Ramesh's request - web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

For Ramesh, this is my jdbc.properties, located in the root directory (/src/java/jdbc.properties)

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xx:3306/x
jdbc.username=y
jdbc.password=z


hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
```

Answer (score 8):

add this bean in your `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location"><value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value></property>
    </bean>
```

update this in web.xml instead of listener

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet
      </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Tried that, but got the same error.  Very frustrating.  This must be simpler than I am making it.

Comment: Added web.xml per your request.   Thanks.

Comment: where is your jdbc.properties

Comment: Please see above for jdbc.properties.

Comment: it should be in your classpath means src folder.

Comment: Hi Ramesh.  I believe it is in the right place.  If I move it, I get real ugly errors.  If I change the password, I get database errors.

Comment: From the path you are using, I will guess you are using maven to build.  You probably need to move your jdbc.properties file to src/main/resources - this is where to place non-java files what you want to get into your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was the result of an error in my java code. It required calling [`configure()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#configure%28%29) on the `Configuration` before calling `buildSessionFactory()`.

The javadoc for `configure()` method:

> Use the mappings and properties specified in an application resource
>   named hibernate.cfg.xml.

**Broken Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

        factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(); // missing the configure() call

        Session s = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = s.beginTransaction();
```

**Solution:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

        factory = cfg.configure().buildSessionFactory();

        Session s = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = s.beginTransaction();
```

Note: I was not using a Spring config.