# Single MySQL instance + Hibernate Config vs Multiple MySQL instances

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, database-design, high-availability

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to change my hibernate config and use a single instance of MySQL (rather than the multiple MySQL instances I currently have):

I have a Java app using hibernate, talking to 2 schemas, config example as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Foo", schema="SchemaA")
public class FooSchemaA

@Entity
@Table(name="Bar", schema="SchemaB")
public class BarSchemaB

<bean name="datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> 
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SchemaA"/> 
    <property name="user" value="root"/> 
    <property name="password" value="password"/> 
</bean>
```

The complexity comes in that I have the Java app running 5 times (on different boxes). I don't require the Java apps to be sharing data so host 5 separate MySQL instances (with identical schemas), one on each box.

I'm now trying to move to an HA solution. If I keep the current config I'd end up with 10 MySQL instances. It just doesn't feel right.. is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a HA database is hard to get right and there is no added benefit if you host the database on the same box as the application.
Typically, a box hosting a server application requires different care/maintenance than a box hosting a RDBMS (e.g. data backup), especially if you want a HA database.

So, assuming one box with a RDMS can handle all the requests from the applications, move your database to a separate box and have the applications access "//virt-address:3306/App01_SchemaA", "//virt-address:3306/App01_SchemaB", etc.. The "virt-address" is a virtual address that resolves to a real address (like "db01-address", "db02-address") via a load-balancer. Using a virtual address is the first step in a HA setup: when one database goes down, the load-balancer can direct traffic to another one that is up. Ofcourse the application needs to be able to refresh database connections when such a switch occurs.

Second step is configuring the RDBMS in a HA setup. A common approach is a master/slave setup (and since you now have 1 box with 1 RDBMS, you only have to worry about 1 HA setup) and switch the slave to master as soon as the master goes down. Drawback is that you have to do some manual work to bring the original master back in sync once it is up again. Another approach is to have a master/master so that you do not have to switch a slave to master. Drawback is that this is harder to setup: both databases need to sync writes.

Whichever HA setup you choose, maintaining 1 setup is always better than maintaining 2 separate setups. While you're at it, you might also want to think about/preapre for  "disaster recovery" (what will you do when all 'live' RDBMS boxes in one location short-circuit?).

Comment: Thanks for that @vanOekel, it is useful to have a good explanation of HA. To be quite honest though it's not really the issue I have at the moment - my question is whether it is possible to have the same schema on a mysql instance multiple times (or have different schemas that hibernate can be told about at runtime) so that multiple instances of the same app (with the same hibernate config) can be executed.. does that make sense?

Comment: @James Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10192241/3080094) for "different schemas at runtime"?

Comment: That kind of thing but unfortunately that wouldn't work as the schemas are specified in the hibernate annotations (as well as one of them in the connection String)

Comment: So basically hard-coded? Then I would advise to make that configurable instead of trying to solve the problem in the database.